Evolveum MidPoint Github CI/CD
new to MIdPoint, just deployed it on an EC2 instance using docker-compose.yml file provided by Evolveum and I dont seem to find any of the config files in the docker containers
My question is how to properly set it up to use Github with CI/CD? I would like to be able to change and push from Github changes like config files, styling (maybe) etc.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
